# Can I track multiple pages on the same domain, in a single Google Analytics goal/event?

Tags: google-analytics, joomla

These are the steps on my site:

Step 1: User enters data in a form and submits it.

Step 2: User is redirected to a Plug n Pay page (which is still on the same domain), where they enter their payment information.

Step 3: User is then redirected to the success page.

I would like to track this process as a single event/goal. From what I have read on other sites, I assume I'll have to use ecommerce feature on Google Analytics.

Comment: I also read that this can be done with segments, but I'm wondering if use segments is a better way for tracking this scenario than using ecommerce

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need a Funnel: Goal type Destination with steps. 
At first you need to set sending of virtual pages for successful form submission and successful payment.

If you want to track transactions, you need to set ecommerce feature.
If you want to measure payment just as fact (without informations about money), you can use event or virtual page.

Virtual page URLs you need to add in Goal settings, and the main field in goal will real URL of your final page (success-page).